# react native with expo-location showing Cannot read property 'requestForegroundPermissionsAsync' of undefined

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I'm trying to use expo-location with the following code :

```
import * as Location from "expo-location";
import * as TaskManager from 'expo-task-manager';
React.useEffect(() => {
    const config = async () => {
        let resf = await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();
        let resb = await Location.requestBackgroundPermissionsAsync();
        if (resf.status != 'granted' && resb.status !== 'granted') {
            console.log('Permission to access location was denied');
        } else {
            console.log('Permission to access location granted');
        }
    };

    config();
}, []);
```

but getting the following error  :

```
 WARN  Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'requestForegroundPermissionsAsync' of undefined
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'requestForegroundPermissionsAsync' of undefined
at ?anon_0_ (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.fammap&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:119292:75)
at next (native)
at asyncGeneratorStep (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.fammap&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:20670:26)
at _next (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.fammap&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:20689:29)
at anonymous
```

Please suggest what I'm doing wrong here,

i have added all the permissions in the Android xml file

Comment: What is your SDK version?

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue. In my case the problem was, that I did not properly prepare my project for the use of expo modules.

Following precicely the expo installation procedure [Install Expo Modules](https://docs.expo.dev/bare/installing-expo-modules/) solved the issue for me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).